# HTML Tables on PHP

Tags: html

My friend and I are doing something advance on html table tags on php.

We want to generate  tags on php as engine but every time we add the ending tag the resulting render on the browser destroys the table layout because it is adding </td> at the end.

Questions

1. It is possible to have td tags without ending tags? Is it really a
   good practice?
2. Is there any work around because when he didn't place
   ending td tags the firebug is actually showing a complete td tag.

Comment: Is it possible?  Probably... whether it works or not will depend on the browser. I wouldn't count on it working how you expect in every browser, nor working consistently in every browser.  I don't really understand your problem to offer suggestions for a work-around. Can you post some sample HTML code so I understand better?

Comment: Browsers will attempt to fix bad html - so not including td tags may 'work', but only because the browser is trying to fix your mistakes. Post your php as well as broken html along with a definition of 'break' and someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omitting the `</td>` tag is perfectly valid.

In HTML4, the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) says:

> ```
> <!ELEMENT (TH|TD)  - O (%flow;)*       -- table header cell, table data cell-->
> ```

(The `O` means the tag is optional)

In HTML5, the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#optional-tags) says

> A td element's end tag may be omitted if the td element is immediately
>   followed by a td or th element, or if there is no more content in the
>   parent element.

If the rest of your mark-up is valid, then the browser parser will infer the end tag correctly in the appropriate place.

So, if adding the close tag is breaking your table, it's a racing certainty that you're doing something else wrong. If you post your mark-up we can guide you to what the problem is, otherwise I recommend that you [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your generated web page.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is well appreciated.